# Docker cannot find file with personal python functions

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I am building a personal project with FastAPI where I have my main FastAPI file, main.py which is calling functions from another file called functions.py

the structure looks like this

```
app
|
|--main.py
|--functions.py
```

Dockerfile is outside app folder
with Docker I execute the following command

```
COPY ./app /code/app
```

to copy the files to the app folder

Now, on my computer I am able to execute the following import

```
from functions import functionname
```

but when I try to run a container from the image I get the error

```
 File "/code/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from functions import functionname
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'
```

I am working on a Mac and I try to run the container from image on ubuntu

As described above I get the error when running the image.

Comment: Try to add `WORKDIR /code/app/` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I solved the issue by uploading the image to the server, and running the container with exec and -it flags. The issue was of python file imports, which for some reasons was being handled differently on my Mac. For instance I added a dot (.) in front of the "functions"  in the import and the issue went away. There was another issue, where I had to add "app."  in front of the import. Thank you for the support Andrey and Ulrich